# ASP.NET Assign Role by CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am using VS2005 C#.

I have a list of users and 2 checkboxes. The checkboxes each indicate `Administrator` and `User`. When a user is selected, the respective checkboxes will be *checked* according to the roles assigned to the user.

Now I am trying to add/remove roles from the selected user by checking/unchecking the checkboxes but I am having some problems. The page reloads for a moment and resets the checkbox status back to the original, and the role is not changed.

Below is my code snippets:

---

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="adminCB" runat="server" Text="Administrator" OnCheckedChanged="Admin_CC" AutoPostBack="true"/><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="userCB" runat="server" Text="User" OnCheckedChanged="User_CC" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

---

```
protected void Admin_CC(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (adminCB.Checked)
    {

        Roles.AddUserToRole(UsersListBox3.SelectedItem.Value, "Administrator");

        // Re-bind users in role to GridView.

        usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole(RolesListBox.SelectedItem.Value);
        UsersInRoleGrid.DataSource = usersInRole;
        UsersInRoleGrid.DataBind();

    }

    if (adminCB==null)
    {

        Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(UsersListBox3.SelectedItem.Value, "Administrator");

        // Re-bind users in role to GridView.

        usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole(RolesListBox.SelectedItem.Value);
        UsersInRoleGrid.DataSource = usersInRole;
        UsersInRoleGrid.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Anyone can spot my mistake for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the check box buttons in an update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="adminCB" runat="server" Text="Administrator" OnCheckedChanged="Admin_CC" AutoPostBack="true"/><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="userCB" runat="server" Text="User" OnCheckedChanged="User_CC" AutoPostBack="true"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: just edited my comment. you might need a scriptmanager at the top of the apsx page.

Comment: i am using VS2005, and I don't think updatepanel is supported. thanks anyway

Comment: VS 2005 should have it i think. The control is under ajax extensions. http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/IntroductionUpdatePanel.aspx